# Does modifying a managed object in a parent context propagate down to child contexts when performing a child fetch in Core Data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I've setup 2 NSManagedContext in a child-parent context in Core Data.

```
    _mainContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
    [_mainContext setParentContext:_parentContext];
    [_mainContext setMergePolicy:NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy];

    _importContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
    [_importContext setParentContext:_mainContext];
    [_importContext setMergePolicy:NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy];
```

What happens if I execute the following in order ("fetch" meaning NSFetchRequest):

1. Fetch Managed object A in mainContext.
2. Fetch Managed object A in importContext.
3. Update object A in mainContext.
4. Fetch Managed object A in importContext.

importContext (child) -> mainContext (parent) -> Persist Store Coordinator

My question is, at step 4, will the object that was fetched in the importContext have the updated changes I made at step 3 in the mainContext? Reading articles on the web seem to indicate that changes made in a parentContext are not propagated down to child context if the child context has already fetched the data (because contexts are cached?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changes from a child context are propagated to the parent when the child is saved, not during fetching. Changes do not move in the other direction.

In your scenario...

#### Fetch Managed object A in mainContext.

**mainContext** will execute a fetch request against it's `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`. The coordinator will locate the store that should service the request and give it the fetch. The persistent store will return a result, and depending on the store keep an in-memory copy of the row data. **mainContext** will now have an in-memory copy of this object (but not necessarily any of it's property values).

#### Fetch Managed object A in importContext.

**importContext** has no in-memory reference to this object, so it will pass the fetch to it's parent, **mainContext**. **mainContext** will pass back the reference to it's in-memory object A. If **mainContext** did not previously fetch the object, or if it was turned into a fault, **mainContext** would fetch all the way to the persistent store. Fetches and `objectWithID:` only go as many levels as they need to.

#### Update object A in mainContext.

The in-memory object A in **mainContext** is changed.

#### Fetch Managed object A in importContext.

The in-memory object A in **importContext** is returned. The changes made in mainContext will not be present in this object.

It's important to remember that when a context is created it's a "snapshot" of the state of it's parent. Subsequent changes to the parent will not be visible in the child unless the child is somehow invalidated (i.e. faulted or discarded).

[You can see how changes propogate in this animation](https://vimeo.com/101448932).

Comment: I have just stumbled into this issue. Seems very strange that changes cannot be propagated from parent to child (with mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification: for example). I am currently experimenting the reset: whenever the parent saves, followed by notifying all views that are interested in the child to re-fetch and update. It seems to me that propagation from parent to child is necessary when changes from other threads come via the persistent store (or mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:).

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "fetched"? A fetched results controller?

From my perspective, the answer to your question is a general "yes". Assuming a shared parent context of some kind, two contexts will get the newest object, if one context saves with a modified object, and the other context does something to load it again, for example, uses the objectID and `- objectWithID:` on the other context, to reload it.

Comment: In terms of "fetching", I meant something like using the NSFetchRequest object to lookup fetch the object again.

NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    
NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription
                                             entityForName:@"ManagedItem" inManagedObjectContext:context];